# How can display different pages by one function and how should declare links in menu?

Tags: codeigniter, menu

headerview.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
```

footerview.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

controllers/main.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {
 function index(){
     $this->load->view('headerview');
     $this->load->view('homeview');
     $this->load->view('footerview');
  } 

}
?>
```

how can I show view/about_us_view.php, view/contact.php etc pages by one function ?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all ur view pages are in root views folder

Controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

 function index($page = 'homeview')
{

    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/'.$page.'.php')){

        show_404();
    }
    else{

    $this->load->view('headerview');
    $this->load->view( $page);
    $this->load->view('footerview');
        }

}

}
```

Header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/main');?>">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/main/index/about_us_view');?>">About Us</a></li>
                <li><?php echo base_url('index.php/main/index/contact');?>">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
```

the basic url pattern is given below

```
http://example.com/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]
```

In the index function we are passing the page name as an argument

To view contact page

```
<?php echo base_url('index.php/main/index/contact');?>
```

Here

controller:main

method:index

argument:contact

Also autoload the url helper in config/autoload.php.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: the about us and contact page not showing. and "$page = 'homeview'" isn't this fixed there for homeview.php only ? so how can show the other pages ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the following:

headerview.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

homeview.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('headerview'); ?>
<div id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="What Should I write Here ?">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>  
<?php $this->load->view('footerview'); ?>
```

And footerview.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

And controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {
 function index(){
     $this->load->view('homeview');
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry, thiss not what I was asking.

Comment: What about at "homeview " to write $this->load->view('about_us_view'); ?

Comment: please try to understand what I asked in my question. its about loading pages by one function. not by doing $this->load->view('page_name') for every page.

Comment: May be this help to you? 
function index(){
     $html = $this->load->view('headerview', array(), true);
     $html .= $this->load->view('homeview', array(), true);
     $html .= $this->load->view('footerview', array(), true);
     echo $html;
  }